# Docker: ERROR Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I'm using docker-compose for nginx service, here is the **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:


services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      - laravel
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql


  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

This is the **default.conf** file

```
server{
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

This is the result of docker-compose up:

> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create
>   failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused
>   "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58:
>   mounting \\"/d/wamp64/www/instawash/nginx/default.conf\\" to rootfs
>   \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a0da06d30448a2583f346955c853cd3343982d96fb5e81b23be4cabad75a3c6b/merged\\"
>   at
>   \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a0da06d30448a2583f346955c853cd3343982d96fb5e81b23be4cabad75a3c6b/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\"
>   caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a
>   directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host
>   path exists and is the expected type

**Tree directory**:

```
    ├─── mysql/
    ├─── nginx/
    └─── src/
         docker-compose.yml
         Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The target of a volume in a docker-compose file can't be a file, it must be a directory.

So instead of this :

```
  - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

You probably want this :

```
  - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

See : https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Thanks. I have been bothered by this error too. It worked.

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is the default.conf doesn't exists in container, but file to file works in docker-compose (If exists).

But thanks any way

Comment: My Previous commentary is wrong, I post the another alternative, but you can do file to file in docker-compose

Comment: In my case this sorta worked, ie. containers started running, but nothing really worked. Our DevOps created `/.docker/` folder with sample `docker-compose.yaml` and other (nginx, xdebug, etc.) configs, so the solution was to (first revert the change from this answer, and then) copy the docker-compose file to root and run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d` from there.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the volumes and rebuild the container with no cache. I did it like this `docker-compose down -v` , then `docker-compose build --pull --no-cache` and finally `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

In my case (It's a rare case) in my development environment I had to add the disk letter in the path for example: c:/data/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

In other configurations it works without letter but for it not : S
/data/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue and i solved it by changing the target's volume of the docker-compose of the nginx config to :

```
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html
  - ./nginx/default.conf
```

Which is the name and path to my nginx directory.